# Problem updating data in an api with mui TextField inputs

Tags: reactjs, jsonplaceholder

I'm making a post admin tool with jsonplaceholder api and I'm having a problem with the put method. How can I update the text input modifications? It's not working even with the fixed data.

```
const EditPost = ({ match }) => {  
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        title: "",
        body: "",
    });
    const [error] = useState("");
    const { id } = match.params;
    const [post, setPost] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
        .then((response) => {
            setPost(response.data);
            });
        }, []);

    const updatePost = () => {
        axios
        .put(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`, {
            title: "Hello World!",
            body: "Post updated."
        })
        .then((response) => {
            setPost(response.data);
        });
    }
```

```
<form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={updatePost}>
                <TextField 
                    id="outlined-basic" 
                    label="Title" 
                    defaultValue={post.title || ""} 
                    name="title"
                    type="text" 
                    onChange="" />
                <TextField 
                    id="outlined-multiline-flexible" 
                    label="Body" 
                    defaultValue={post.body || ""} 
                    name="body"
                    type="text" 
                    onChange="" />
                <Button 
                    type="submit">
                        Update Post
                </Button>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to more clearly explain the question you're asking or problem you're having. If you remove the redundant tag information about React.js, your entire title is *Updating data*, which is a meaningless phrase. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to be of use to a future site user who is skimming through a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem, and your current title is useless in that sense. Thanks.

Comment: Please take a moment to read [ask].

Comment: Seems to me there might be something wrong with `TextField`, but you didn't say what library that came from (is it mui TextField?) or if it is built by you. If it is from the `mui` library, the only thing I think may be an issue is that you have used `defaultValue` which is only used for uncontrolled textfield (see the [difference here](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#uncontrolled-vs-controlled)). Instead you should set the `onChange` prop to a function which updates the state, and provide a `value` prop using the state. Both of these are needed if the field is to update the state.

Comment: Yes, it's from the mui library (it's updated in the title now). I use 'defaultValue' because with 'value' I couldn't modify the textfields, why could it be? I have tried some handle event function but I had no change neither.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you restructure your component as such:

```
const EditPost = ({ match }) => {
    const [error] = useState("");
    const { id } = match.params;
    const [postTitle, setPostTitle] = useState("");
    const [postBody, setPostBody] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
            .then((response) => {
                setPost(response.data);
            });
    }, []);

    const updatePost = () => {
        axios
            .put(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`, {
                title: postTitle,
                body: postBody,
            })
            .then(({ data }) => {
                setPostTitle(data.title);
                setPostBody(data.body);
            });
    };

    return (
        <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={updatePost}>
            <TextField
                id="outlined-basic"
                label="Title"
                value={postTitle}
                name="title"
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setPostTitle(e.target.value)}
            />
            <TextField
                id="outlined-multiline-flexible"
                label="Body"
                value={postBody}
                name="body"
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setPostBody(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button type="submit">Update Post</Button>
        </form>
    );
};
```

To be able to update the state as the user types, you need to control your form fields. The way to do this is to supply each field with a `value` prop, and use the `onChange` prop to update the state of the fields. This is the [recommended](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#uncontrolled-vs-controlled) by the mui team.

Furthermore, we have moved our state from a single object (which is reminiscent of the days of class components), to separate state objects (`postBody` and `postTitle`) which should reduce the number of times parts of the component have to re-render.